# Problem copying an Excel row last value becomes NaN in Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, excel, kendo-grid

I am having `kendogrid` which is editable, we can enter vales from January to December.

If I am entering the value,then it is working fine,but when i copied the value from excel then the last value becomes `NaN`.

Example if I copied 5 cell value from Excel then first 4 will be pasted correctly,the fifth one becomed `NaN`.

The kendo Grid Columns are like below:

```
column.Bound(p => p.M1).Title(CommonFunctions.GetMonthName(1))
                       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-right" })
                       .Format("{0:N4}")
                       .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-center" })
                       .Width(75);
```

Comment: Before assigning the value, check if the value is empty or not, 'NAN' is shown when there is either no data or wrong conversion of data.

Comment: there is numeric data only, Manually i am copying 5 cell value and pasting that in grid.the last call value becomes NaN.